# Proving Normal subgroups and abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups

My questions is

Let H be a subgroup of G which contains all products of type $x^{-1}y^{-1}xy\in H  \forall x,y\in G$.

Prove that $h\in H$that $ghg^{-1}\in H$. So H is normal.

Then consider the factor group $G/H$. Prove $G/H$ is abelian, so $(aH)(bH)=(bH)(aH)$. 
I know that I have to use $b^{-1}a^{-1}ba\in H$ to show that $ba\in (aH)(bH).$

Any tips? I dont know how to make this any clearer because this is all I have been given.

For the first part, I know that in order for $ghg^{-1}\in H$, $ghg^{-1}=gx^{-1}y^{-1}xyg^{-1}$=$(g^{-1})^{-1}x^{-1}y^{-1}xyg^{-1}.$ Im stuck after that

Comment: To answer one of your questions, the factor group $G/H$ is the group whose elements are cosets with multiplication defined by $aHbH = abH$. Other than that, I don't understand what you're asking - you should try to tidy up your question a bit.

Comment: Jack, I'd like to see if I understand your question correctly. Your only assumption about $H$ is that it is a subgroup of $G$ that contains all products of the form $x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$, where $x, y \in G$. From that you want to prove that $H$ is normal, and that $G/H$ is Abelian. You *do not* assume that $H$ is the subgroup generated by those elements, only that it contains them. Is that correct? The result will be correct either way.

Comment: You can't assume that any $h \in H$ can be written as $x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we prove that $H$ is normal. $\forall h \in H,g\in G$, suppose $h=xyx^{-1}y^{-1}=:[x, y]$, we have
$$ghg^{-1}=g[x,y]g^{-1}=gxyx^{-1}y^{-1}g^{-1}=gx(g^{-1}g)y(g^{-1}g)x^{-1}(g^{-1}g)y^{-1}g^{-1}=(gxg^{-1})(gyg^{-1})(gxg^{-1})^{-1}(gyg^{-1})^{-1}=[gxg^{-1},gyg^{-1}] \in H.$$
For arbitrary $h$, the proof follows from what have been proved.
Next, we prove that $G/H$ is abelian. $\forall x, y\in G$, we have
$$\bar x\bar y\bar x^{-1}\bar y^{-1}=\overline{xyx^{-1}y^{-1}}=\bar e,$$
since $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}\in H$. Hence, $\bar x\bar y=\bar y\bar x$, which completes the proof.
**Note**: $\bar x:=xH$.

Comment: The subgroup $H$ is called the _derived subgroup_ or _commutator subgroup_ of $G$.

Comment: can you explain the G/H part better? mainly that equation where everything is the identity?

Comment: Since $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}\in H$, it lies in the same coset as $e$, which means $\overline{xyx^{-1}y^{-1}}=\bar e$.

Comment: and wherever we see x bar or y bar or x^-1 bar, it should be xH and yH and x^-1H. right?

Comment: Yes, that's a common notation for cosets.

Comment: Eclipse Sun, if I understand you, you're letting $h \in H$, and from that you deduce that $h$ can be written in the form $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$. That's incorrect.

Comment: @user187373 Yes, and I have corrected it now.

Answer (score 0):

Let $h \in H$ and $g \in G$. Then $ghg^{-1} = (ghg^{-1}h^{-1})h$ is the product of two elements of $H$, hence belongs to $H$. (Take $x = g^{-1}$ and $y = h^{-1}$.) Therefore $H$ is normal.

Now let $\overline{x},\overline{y}$ be arbitrary elements of $G/H$, represented respectively by $x,y \in G$. In $G/H$, we have
$$\left(\overline{x}\right)^{-1}\left(\overline{y}\right)^{-1}\overline{x}\overline{y} = \overline{x^{-1}y^{-1}xy} = 1,$$
since $x^{-1}y^{-1}xy \in H$. Multiplying on the left by $\overline{y}\overline{x}$, we find $\overline{x}\overline{y}= \overline{y}\overline{x}$, proving that $G/H$ is commutative.

NOTE. The stated condition is equivalent to the condition that $H$ should contain the *commutator subgroup* of $G$, which is the subgroup of $G$ generated by the commutators $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$.